# Shopping cart WP doesn't show selected items until page is refreshed

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, refresh, cart, shopping-cart

Currently im trying to build a webshop in WordPress with WooCommerce.
There is a shopping cart build in but it doesn't refresh itself once an item is selected to be added to the cart.

However if I refresh the page it does show the item.
Is there a way to make this shopping cart dynamic and change without using refresh?

```
var $woo_widget_cssclass;
var $woo_widget_description;
var $woo_widget_idbase;
var $woo_widget_name;

/**
 * constructor
 *
 * @access public
 * @return void
 */
function WooCommerce_Widget_Cart() {

    /* Widget variable settings. */
    $this->woo_widget_cssclass      = 'widget_shopping_cart';
    $this->woo_widget_description   = __( "Display the user's Cart in the sidebar.", 'woocommerce' );
    $this->woo_widget_idbase        = 'woocommerce_widget_cart';
    $this->woo_widget_name          = __( 'WooCommerce Cart', 'woocommerce' );

    /* Widget settings. */
    $widget_ops = array( 'classname' => $this->woo_widget_cssclass, 'description' => $this->woo_widget_description );

    /* Create the widget. */
    $this->WP_Widget( 'shopping_cart', $this->woo_widget_name, $widget_ops );
}


/**
 * widget function.
 *
 * @see WP_Widget
 * @access public
 * @param array $args
 * @param array $instance
 * @return void
 */
function widget( $args, $instance ) {
    global $woocommerce;

    extract( $args );

    if ( is_cart() || is_checkout() ) return;

    $title = apply_filters('widget_title', empty( $instance['title'] ) ? __('Cart', 'woocommerce') : $instance['title'], $instance, $this->id_base );
    $hide_if_empty = empty( $instance['hide_if_empty'] )  ? 0 : 1;

    echo $before_widget;

    if ( $title )
        echo $before_title . $title . $after_title;

    $woocommerce->mfunc_wrapper( 'woocommerce_mini_cart()', 'woocommerce_mini_cart', array( 'list_class' => $hide_if_empty ? 'hide_cart_widget_if_empty' : '' ) );

    echo $after_widget;

    if ( $hide_if_empty && sizeof( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() ) == 0 ) {
        $woocommerce->add_inline_js( "
            jQuery('.hide_cart_widget_if_empty').closest('.widget').hide();
            jQuery('body').bind('adding_to_cart', function(){
                jQuery(this).find('.hide_cart_widget_if_empty').closest('.widget').fadeIn();
            });
        " );
    }
}


/**
 * update function.
 *
 * @see WP_Widget->update
 * @access public
 * @param array $new_instance
 * @param array $old_instance
 * @return array
 */
function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
    $instance['title'] = strip_tags( stripslashes( $new_instance['title'] ) );
    $instance['hide_if_empty'] = empty( $new_instance['hide_if_empty'] ) ? 0 : 1;
    return $instance;
}


/**
 * form function.
 *
 * @see WP_Widget->form
 * @access public
 * @param array $instance
 * @return void
 */
function form( $instance ) {
    $hide_if_empty = empty( $instance['hide_if_empty'] ) ? 0 : 1;
    ?>
    <p><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>"><?php _e('Title:', 'woocommerce') ?></label>
    <input type="text" class="widefat" id="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id('title') ); ?>" name="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_name('title') ); ?>" value="<?php if (isset ( $instance['title'])) {echo esc_attr( $instance['title'] );} ?>" /></p>

    <p><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id('hide_if_empty') ); ?>" name="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_name('hide_if_empty') ); ?>"<?php checked( $hide_if_empty ); ?> />
    <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('hide_if_empty'); ?>"><?php _e( 'Hide if cart is empty', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label></p>
    <?php
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved, For anyone who has the same problem. In your wordpress backend go to WooCommerce>Settings and then turn of the ajax for the cart functionality. It then loads the page on itself once an item is added.